# Rubbe ec2r : Unable to connect with ssh

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, ruby-on-rails-4, rubber

I followed the railscasts and with basic configurations 
such as  `image_id: ami-3f32ac3e` (Ubuntu Server 12.04.3 LTS 64 bit), `app_name: myapp`, `app_user: jashwant` , I tried to deploy with rubber.

Everything went smooth. I now have a running instance, but at the end I am getting 

`` Trying to enable root login
  * 2013-11-09 17:03:33 executing `rubber:_ensure_key_file_present'
  * 2013-11-09 17:03:33 executing `rubber:_allow_root_ssh'
  * executing "sudo -p 'sudo password: '  bash -l -c 'mkdir -p /root/.ssh && cp /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys /root/.ssh/'"
    servers: ["54.238.122.222"]
 ** Failed to connect to 54.238.122.122, retrying
  * 2013-11-09 17:03:37 executing `rubber:_ensure_key_file_present'
  * 2013-11-09 17:03:37 executing `rubber:_allow_root_ssh'
  * executing "sudo -p 'sudo password: '  bash -l -c 'mkdir -p /root/.ssh && cp /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys /root/.ssh/'"
    servers: ["54.238.122.122"] ``

You can see the error [here](https://github.com/rubber/rubber/blob/master/lib/rubber/recipes/rubber/setup.rb#L58)

I concluded from here that, I need to set `:initial_ssh_user` in `config/deploy.rb`

I already saw,

`set :user, 'root'
set :password, nil`

in `config/deploy.rb`

So, I added `set :initial_ssh_user, 'ubuntu'`. But the error remains the same.

If I change `set :user, 'root'` to `set :user, 'ubuntu'`, then I get 

`` Trying to enable root login
  * 2013-11-09 17:13:48 executing `rubber:_direct_connection_54.238.122.122_411'
  * executing "echo"
    servers: ["54.238.122.122"]
 ** Failed to connect to 54.238.122.122, retrying ``

Things I have checked after googling:

1. It's not happening because Amazon instance is still starting. I have waited long after the instance has started. Also,  I get the same error when I do `ALIAS=production cap rubber:refresh`
2. I am able to successfully log in to this new instance via ssh (providing username as `ubuntu` ). So, key file is okay.
3. I have already added the key with `ssh-add`
4. Key file in .`ec2` directory does not have `.pem` extension.
5. I do not have duplicate entries in my `etc/hosts` on Amazon instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that rubber wasn't able to read from private key. I fixed that and it worked.

Comment: * 2014-06-17 21:08:13 executing `rubber:_ensure_key_file_present'
  * 2014-06-17 21:08:13 executing `rubber:_allow_root_ssh'
  * executing "sudo -p 'sudo password: '  bash -l -c 'mkdir -p /root/.ssh && cp /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys /root/.ssh/'"
    servers: ["54.238.183.162"]
 ** Failed to connect to 54.238.183.162, retrying

Comment: Have you checked the 5 points, I have mentioned. Are you sure, key file is present and readable ?

Comment: I have resolved it by rename(delete the pen extension) the .pem file that download from AWS.But next I got another problem , it's too disappoint ,finally I give up ,and choose OpsWorks that support by official.  Thank you.

Comment: If you are using `micro` instance, you'll definitely find a lot of issues. Consider upgrading your instance and rubber will be a charm ;)

Comment: ....Really? if it's true,the AWS may be some.... you see,I'am beginner in AWS,just need some test/practice for how to use it.Key point: The micro is free.

Comment: Yeap, but I wasted 10 days running micro with rubber. You'll have to customize rubber so that it works with micro. e.g. keep the no of instances to 1. Do assets precompilation locally etc etc.